# How do I sell AND price WooCommerce products at fixed quantities?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Curious issue that might have a simple answer that's for whatever reason alluding me.

In my WooCommerce shop I'm trying to sell business cards.  I want to sell them in lots of either 200 or 400.

I know how to set the step values and limit the minimum and maximum.  The problem is I want the 200 and 400 to be treated as units of 1 and 2 respectively when calculating price - so, say, 200 is $29 and 400 is a discounted $39.  What naturally happens is that 200/400 cards is being multiplied by $29/$39 respectively.

I can't seem to figure this out using any of the available plugins.  If I set the step value at 200 I need to set the product pricing at $0.195 ($39/200) in order to the get the correct total but I don't want the user to see "per (individual) card" pricing in the cart.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Considering that everything works naturally with quantity at 1 and 2 I was thinking about a possible jQuery approach where I simply manipulate the displayed value.  Worried about cross browser support with the HTML5 control/events though.

Comment: I'm intrigued by this, but could you not just leave the quantities as 1,2,3 etc and note somewhere that you are selling boxes/lots of 200?

Comment: Admittedly that was plan A but we have a unique product where we actually sell books of business cards so 1 "order" is 8 "cardbooks" which is, in total, 200 "cards".  I'd prefer to do whatever I can to eliminate as much confusion as possible.

Answer (score 0):

What I would probably do is create a new product type that extends the simple product class. I wasn't going to get into the code at all, but it looks like I've already answered several questions that could be useful to you. This isn't a complete copy-paste solution as this is a pretty sizable job, but this should get you started.

[creating a custom product type](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/120220)

Though I would probably extend `WC_Product_Simple` instead of `WC_Product` because basically this will be the same as a simple product with the following caveats:

You add 1 meta field to define your "lot" size.

[Define product meta fields for custom product type only](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26348545/383847)

Then create your own add to cart template for that type that uses the "lot" size to manipulate the add to quantity inputs (minimum and step).

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_your_type_add_to_cart', array( $this, 'add_to_cart_template' ) );

function custom_type_add_to_cart_template() {

    global $product;

    // Load the add to cart template
    wc_get_template(
        'single-product/add-to-cart/your-type.php',
        array(), // you can pass global variables here, ex: your product's "lot" size would be a good idea
        '',
        YOUR_PLUGIN_PATH . '/templates/'
    );

}
```

Finally, adjust the total price in the cart as `$price * $quantity / $lot_size`.